# Listner to multiple spinners

Tags: android

I need to write a listener for three spinners, by just creating a single listener

Please help me out with that problem to my code given below

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

 Spinner MainSpinner,spinner1,spinner2;

 EditText Edittext;
 TextView TV;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin2);
    final TextView ta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.et2);



    MainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MainSpin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> MainspinAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
            (this, R.array.MainSpin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    MainspinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    MainSpinner.setAdapter(MainspinAdapter);


    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> TempAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
            (this, R.array.Temperature, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> LengthAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
            (this, R.array.Length, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> DigitalAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
            (this, R.array.Digital, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);



}
```

Give some examples to get the logic

Comment: What is that you expect and what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `OnItemSelectedListener` in your Activity and in override method use below code:

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
 if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1)
 {
   //do this                    
 }
 else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
 {
   //do this
 }
```

}